# Google Search Engine returns only 10 results

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-search

I have Java app which uses google search engine. 
  Customsearch custom = new Customsearch(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), httpRequestInitializer);

```
    Customsearch.Cse.List list = custom.cse().list("some query");
    list.setCx(cx);
    list.setKey(key);

   Search result = list.execute();
   List<Result> listResult =  result.getItems();
```

The problem is that listResult.size() = 10.  No matters how much are results actually it returns me first 10 result.

Please help me to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting number of results to return and 10 is a default, api here - https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/customsearch/v1/java/latest/

```
list.setNum(100);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! According to documentation every time when I set number to Customsearch.Cse.List list Object: for example list.setNumber(100) the following exception appears:

Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
This happens when number is > 10